Confusion regarding Do Carmo's definition of a regular surface
In Do Carmo's 'Differential geometry of curves and surfaces', he defines a regular surface in the following way:

A subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular surface if, for each $p \in S$ there exists a neighbourhood  $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and a map $\textbf{x}:U \rightarrow V \cap S$ of an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ onto $V \cap S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that:

$\textbf{x}$ is differentiable.
$\textbf{x}$ is a homeomorphism.
For each $q \in U$, the differential $d\textbf{x}_q:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is injective.


I know he gives his own definition for a differential for regular surfaces, but I originally only had the differential defined for me for differentiable manifolds defined in the following way:

Let $X$ be a second countable Hausdorff space, then a $\textbf{smooth atlas}$ of $X$ is a collection $\mathfrak{A}$ of pairs $(U,\phi)$ such that:

For every pair $(U,\phi)\in \mathfrak{A}$, $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $\phi:U\rightarrow \phi(U)$ is a homeomorphism(continuous, bijective map with a continuous inverse) onto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
$X=\bigcup_{(U,\phi)\in \mathfrak{A}} U$
If $(U,\phi) \in \mathfrak{A}$ and $(V,\psi)\in \mathfrak{A}$ with $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$, then
\begin{equation*}
\psi \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U \cap V) \rightarrow \psi(U \cap V)
\end{equation*}
is differentiable.



A $\textbf{differentiable structure}$ on $X$ is a smooth atlas $\mathfrak{A}$, which is maximal in the sense that if $\mathfrak{A}'$ is a smooth atlas of $X$ and $\mathfrak{A} \subset \mathfrak{A}'$, then $\mathfrak{A} = \mathfrak{A}'$. A $\textbf{differentiable manifold}$ is a second countable Hausdorff space, which is equipped with a differentiable structure.

So, to have these definitions coincide, I have to show that it is a (two-dimensional) differentiable manifold. The set of the maps paired with their respective domains is obviously a smooth atlas, but I struggle to show maximality for it. Or do I first have to extend the atlas given by Do Carmo to a maximal atlas if necessary to then be able to work with it like a differentiable manifold?

You are right that do Carmo's definition is not a maximal atlas, but rather just a standard smooth atlas. To work with it in the sense of your second definition, you need to extend this smooth atlas to a maximal one like you point out.
However, it is worth nothing that there is nothing lost logically in doing this (i.e. the two definitions actually lead to the same thing) because any smooth atlas is contained in a unique maximal one, see Proposition 1.17(a) of John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. As such, many constructions you will see in manifold theory when it comes to proving things are smooth manifolds go by just constructing any smooth atlas for your manifold, then taking the maximal atlas determined by the one you constructed.

Thanks! I was thinking about this for quite some time.
